# How to display text in a textarea by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Can I have a link that when clicked displays text inside a textarea?

This is what I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
mybutton: onclick {
document.myform2.mytextfield2.value = "Test";
}
</script>

<form name="myform2">
<input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Go">
<input type="text" name="mytextfield2">
</form>
```

Please tell me what I got wrong.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please show us _your_ code and don't expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question to add detail to it. Don't do it in comments, as people might not read them.

Comment: I'm new, how do I diplay code without it changing?

Comment: Highlight the code then press the `{}` button (or Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `mybutton: onclick { ... }` is not an executable statement; it's a fragment of code.

There are several ways to fix your code.

**1. Declare a function in the script, and declare an `onclick` event handler in the button.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunc() {
document.myform2.mytextfield2.value = "Test";
}
</script>

<form name="myform2">
<input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Go" onclick="myfunc()">
<input type="text" name="mytextfield2">
</form>
```

**OR 2. Give the button an ID, put the script block after the button, and modify the event handler registration code.**

```
<form name="myform2">
<input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Go" id="mybutton">
<input type="text" name="mytextfield2">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = function() {
document.myform2.mytextfield2.value = "Test";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I make the "go" button a link instead?

Comment: Use case #1, and the HTML code `<a href="#" onclick="myfunc()">My link</a>`.

Comment: I see that every link needs a "href" so you filled it with "#" because no window or tab would be opened. I am surprised that it doesn't cause an error.

Comment: Using `#` for a link is standard practice for JavaScript links. Moreover, it's a legal URL because `#` signifies the document fragment.